# Have R look for files in a library directory

Tags: linux, r

I am using R, on linux. 
I have a set a functions that I use often, and that I have saved in different .r script files. Those files are in ~/r_lib/.

I would like to include those files without having to use the fully qualified name, but just "file.r". Basically I am looking the same command as -I in the c++ compiler.

I there a way to set the include file from R, in the .Rprofile or .Renviron file?

Thanks

Comment: to take a slightly different approach, you could consider wrapping up `file.r` into a package for yourself. I had a similar workflow to yours for a long while, and then someone pointed me in the direction of [roxygen](http://roxygen.org/). Since I had commented by initial file fairly diligently, it was a very trivial task to turn that into the roxygen format.

Comment: Build your own package with all your functions at the finger tips. It's easy as pie or easier. I have recorded my experience here: http://danganothererror.wordpress.com/2010/07/23/building-an-r-package-under-windows-without-c-c-or-fortran-code/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `sourceDir` function in the Examples section of `?source`:

```
sourceDir <- function(path, trace = TRUE, ...) {
   for (nm in list.files(path, pattern = "\\.[RrSsQq]$")) {
      if(trace) cat(nm,":")           
      source(file.path(path, nm), ...)
      if(trace) cat("\n")
   }
}
```

And you may want to use `sys.source` to avoid cluttering your global environment.

Answer (score 1):

If you set the `chdir` parameter of source to `TRUE`, then the `source` calls within the included file will be relative to its path. Hence, you can call:

```
source("~/r_lib/file.R",chdir=T)
```

It would probably be better not to have source calls within your "library" and make your code into a package, but sometimes this is convenient.

Comment: See the `chdir` argument to `source`

Comment: @hadley Thanks! I've updated my answer accordingly. I looked for such an argument to `source`, but obviously not hard enough.

Answer (score 0):

Get all the files of your directory, in your case

```
d <- list.files("~/r_lib/")
```

then you can load them with a function of the `plyr` package

```
library(plyr)  
l_ply(d, function(x) source(paste("~/r_lib/", x, sep = "")))
```

If you like you can do it in a loop as well or use a different function onstead of `l_ply`. Conventional loop:

```
for (i in 1:length(d)) source(paste("~/r_lib/", d[[i]], sep = ""))
```

Answer (score 0):

Write your own `source()` wrapper?

```
mySource <- function(script, path = "~/r_lib/", ...) {
    ## paste path+filename
    fname <- paste(path, script, sep = "")
    ## source the file
    source(fname, ...)
}
```

You could stick that in your `.Rprofile` do is will be loaded each time you start R.

If you want to load all the R files, you can extend the above easily to source all files at once

```
mySource <- function(path = "~/r_lib/", ...) {
    ## list of files
    fnames <- list.files(path, pattern = "\\.[RrSsQq]$")
    ## add path
    fnames <- paste(path, fnames, sep = "")
    ## source the files
    lapply(fnames, source, ...)
    invisible()
}
```

Actually, though, you'd be better off starting your own private package and loading that.

Comment: Generally better to use `file.path` to create paths.